# Adding Desktop Notifications to Your Web Applications even if user not in the Web Application or user logged off from the site

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I am trying to implement a browser notification so that even if user not in the web application(ASP.NET MVC Web Application), we can push notifications through browser.Is there any possible way to implement this?Also tried

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/adding-desktop-notifications-to-your-web-applications  this also.Can anyone please help?

If I use SignalR to communicate Client-Server ,can get notification if user close the browser,and the users session exist in browser?

Comment: You already know one possible way to do it. Go ahead and do it. If you face specific problem, post question with problem details.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, what you are asking is not possible for a completely web based application. In order for you to post any kind of notification to the desktop that is not directly triggered by the web app, as in the user does not have the app open in their browser, you would need to have a process running on the user's system polling for updates to display, which falls completely outside of the original question. 
If you are asking how you can create notifications directly from your app itself, whether or not the tab is in focus, then you have already posted the answer yourself.